# QML, GridView delegate: ReferenceError: `<variable_name>` is not defined

Tags: qt, qml, delegates, roles, listmodel

I am struggling with it a bit so far, but couldn't find an answer. Here is the core situation.

I have a GridView with ListModel:

```
GridView {
    id: shapeSidePos
    ...
    model: shapeSidePosList
                
    delegate: ButtonIcon {
        style: ButtonIcon.Styles.Parallel
        icon: path
        ...
        }

    ListModel {
        id: shapeSidePosList
        ListElement { path: "../../images/shape_side_positioning_base.png" }
        ListElement { path: "../../images/shape_side_positioning_right.png" }
        ...
    }
}
```

And in a runtime I get error:

```
ReferenceError: path is not defined
```

The thing is, when I have used e.g. `Rectangle` instead of `ButtonIcon`, everything worked fine! Accessing elements with `model.path` did not work either. In ButtonIcon, `icon` is defined so:

```
property alias icon: buttonIcon.source
```

where buttonIcon is an image with MouseArea.

Been searching through web, found some tricks with JS but that makes things complicated and many developers may use this code later. It would be problematic for them.
However, I can access the right path while referring directly to an index:

```
icon: shapeSidePosList.get(0).path
```

I tried packing delegate into Component, tried DelegateModel, nothing has given the expected result.

I have no idea what is going on,

I would be very thankful for any help provided.

Comment: Could you try with `model.path` or even `modelData.path`? (it makes little sense, but who knows...)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. Thank you!

Comment: There is something missing from your code, could you share more? Is `path` used somewhere else? I recreated your code from what you've written and it works without the error.

Comment: Well, the thing is that when I replace this `ButtonIcon` with anything else, e.g. `Image` or `Text`, everything works fine.

The thing came up to my mind. `ButtonIcon` itself is a bit complicated class, using enums and functions in `color` and `opacity`. Might it be a performance-related issue? I've noticed that things load slower when using `ButtonIcon` instead of e.g. `Text`.

Comment: Do you reference `path` inside `ButtonIcon`?

Comment: No, there is no such property or alias inside `ButtonIcon`. Only property is `icon`, to which I am trying to assign `path`.

Comment: You could try to enforce the `path` property in the delegate with the `required` keyword like shown here https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#view-delegates and see if it yields any other errors.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much! I'd buy you a beer if I could.

Comment: I needed to add `required property var icon` and `required property int index` for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@iam_peter wrote:

> You could try to enforce the path property in the delegate with the required keyword like shown here https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#view-delegates and see if it yields any other errors.

I have added a `required` property to a delegate:

```
    delegate: ButtonIcon {
        required property var path // <-- this
        required property int index // <-- and this

        style: ButtonIcon.Styles.Parallel
        icon: path
        ...
        }
```

and it worked. Thank you very much!

#### Update

The reason has been found. @GrecKo has explained here https://forum.qt.io/topic/141689/qml-gridview-delegate-referenceerror-variable_name-is-not-defined/4:

> The reason is most likely because ButtonIcon has a required property itself. When a delegate has one it doesn't provide model roles as context properties anymore but only set those corresponding to explicit required properties.

And the `ButtonIcon` had a required property indeed.

Comment: You should make `path` a `string` type. Great to hear that it works, but still strange why it didn't work before. I think it has something to do with `ButtonIcon` and its internals. Maybe there is a property named `path` in one of the used items in the component covering the `ListElement` property.

Comment: I will do some more investigation. I tried making path a string and then using `Qt.resolveUrl`, but that didn't work before.

Comment: Got an answer explaining what is happening. Updated post.